# Laravel Newbie ? about DB controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm learning Laravel and I tried to create a page where Laravel populates a table from DB, but I have an error (I did everythin what was in [this PDF file](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_tutorial.pdf) (Page 67-69))

**Error message:**

> FatalThrowableError in ListProductsController.php line 16: Parse
>   error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function
>   (T_FUNCTION)

**ListProductsController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ListProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function inventory(){
    $inventory = DB::select('select * from inventory');
    return view('inventory',['inventory'=>$inventory]);
}
```

**My route:**

```
Route::get('inventory','ListProductsController@inventory');
```

What goes wrong?

Comment: Mention the line 16 in controller code so that we can understand line on which error occurs?

Comment: Line16 is an empty row at the end of the file

Comment: Check the answer given by Alexey Mezenin

Comment: Happy coding :)

Comment: Please use proper spacing for coding for you to read and other as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgot to add `}` at the end:

```
class ListProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function inventory() 
    {
        $inventory = DB::select('select * from inventory');
        return view('inventory',['inventory' => $inventory]);
    }
}
```